# check a key does not exist

Tags: python, key

I have a list like this, below is the example. How can I pull the data without 'hidden' key using python? like the second one.

My code is

```
if tab['label'] == 'toolname' and 'hidden' not in tab :
        print(course['id'], tab['label'], tab['hidden'])
```

I got

> KeyError: 'hidden' error, how to write the code to replace ''hidden' not in tab '

```
[{
    'id': 'context_external_tool_35702',
    'html_url': '/courses/1242593/external_tools/35702',
    'full_url': 'https://url/courses/1242593/external_tools/35702',
    'position': 35,
    'hidden': True,
    'visibility': 'admins',
    'label': 'toolname',
    'type': 'external',
    'url': 'https://url/api/v1/courses/1242593/external_tools/sessionless_launch?id=35702&launch_type=course_navigation'
}

,

{
    'id': 'context_external_tool_35702',
    'html_url': '/courses/1235556/external_tools/35702',
    'full_url': 'https://url/courses/1235556/external_tools/35702',
    'position': 19,
    'visibility': 'admins',
    'label': 'toolname',
    'type': 'external',
    'url': 'https://url/api/v1/courses/1235556/external_tools/sessionless_launch?id=35702&launch_type=course_navigation'
}]
```

Comment: please format your code so it is more readable. you can select text and use Command (or Control) + K to format the code sections of your post.

Comment: So you explicitly check `if 'hidden' not in tab` then you still try to access it `tab['hidden']`? There is some error in your logic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement is working fine. The problem is that the last thing you're printing is `tab['hidden']` when `'hidden'` is not in `tab`. Only print the `id` and `label`.

```
print(course['id'], tab['label'])
```

Comment: Yes, I removed the tab['hidden'], and it worked. thank you so much!